# Can't add another hash to ruby hash array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have a mongoid object

```
@tran = Translations.where({:_id => params[:id]})[0]
```

The object `@tran` has a array of hashes at `@tran[:translations]`

and `result` is another hash

I tried adding `result` to `@tran[:translations]`

```
@tran[:translations] << result
```

but the value of `@tran[:translations]` gets changed to `[{*current value of result*}]` and is not being appended

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Comment: can you show us `p @tran[:translations]`?

Comment: the value of `@tran[:translations` is `[{"value":"hello3","rating":100,"rated":0}]`

Comment: I checked it in my irb, nothing weird there, as you are having..

Comment: I know. That's what is bugging me. It works fine with irb but with rails, It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, if I used

`@tran[:translations] = @tran[:translations] + [result]`

instead of

`@tran[:translations] << result`

It worked fine.